# Communication between Windows 10 Pro computers on LAN using CMD built in functionality

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

Is there a built in service/program on windows 10 that I can use if I have 2 computers on local network that I want quickly from one to send some text to the other? Basically it's just the easiest TCP server & client needed, but I'm wondering if Windows 10 has something like it built in. There is the "msg" command, but I would like it better if I could receive the message in a CMD terminal, and also copying the message content is not comfortable with this program.
Is there something like what I need? I'm using Windows 10, not Windows Server.
Please stick to CMD and don't offer me alternative ways (like downloading a 3rd party software) to accomplish this. Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: No, other than what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a program that does this for you, build-in in windows, but given what you ask is not very large, you may find this answer acceptable.

You can create a share on one of the computers, and share a text document.

On the remote computer, you first need to map a network drive to access the share.

This can be done using `net use x: \\pcname\share` where x: is the letter you want to use, pcname is the name of the pc, and share is the name you gave the shared folder's share.

Locally you can just go to the path directly (or also map the driveletter so that both computers have it appear the same.

On either computer, you can now type:

```
type filename.txt
```

to view the content of the textfile.

Or:

```
echo This is some text I want to share > filename.txt
```

to create a new textfile with the text This is some text I want to share (it clears whatever was in the file)

Or:

echo This is more text >> filename.txt

to add `This is more text` to the file with a newline.

This is obviously not a chat app, but is a good way to communicate between two computers.

You can of course also just open notepad and that file directly. Programs such as Notepad++ and Geany will register when the textfile was changed and ask you if you want to reload it, so realtime communication becomes easier. Its just not in a terminal window anymore.

ADDENDUM:
If it really is your goal to just quickly get a textfile on the other computer, if both computers have a pro license, you should be able to just use `\\pcname\c$`  and use the login credentials of the other computer to quickly access its files and push a file to that computer from explorer.